# Rendering (cycles) glass surrounded by objects

Tags: rendering, glass

I'm new to Blender, currently following some lessons but still a beginner stage.

I've been working on a personal project and encountered a strange behaviour when dealing with glass.
Here's the situation: I'm composing a breakfast scene, and one of the objects is a glass jug with a fake liquid inside.

[image: Situation with only the jug]

All looks good until I make visible any object in near proximity to the jug.
Whatever object is near the glass, causes it to reflect/refract (don't know what's happening tbh) light in a strange way.

[image: Situation with an object near the jug]

Can someone kindly explain to me what am I doing wrong here? I can add more details if needed, just let me know!

Comment: Check if the 2 meshes (glass and liquid) does not overlap collide....

Comment: Ah, I managed to resolve the issue by recalculating normals! :D 
Thanks for the reply anyway!